# Typescript error for union between boolean and object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following context, which is used to show a loader, and also optionally specify its positioning using a string:

```
// True or false => show with default positioning or hide
// can provide object to specify positioning (tailwind class string)
export type LoaderArgs = boolean | { showLoader: boolean; position?: string };

type LoaderContextArgs = [
  LoaderArgs,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<LoaderArgs | undefined>>
];

/**
 * Ctx to provide isLoading and setIsLoading to subcomponents. Is provided with state in outer app component.
 */
export const LoaderContext = React.createContext<LoaderContextArgs>([
  false,
  () => true,
]);
```

What I want is to be able to check if it's an object and showLoader is true, OR if it's equal to true, in order to show my Loader component:

```
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState<LoaderArgs>(false);

  /* (... more code here)*/

      {loader?.showLoader && <Loader />}
```

But this leads to a type error: `Property 'showLoader' does not exist on type 'LoaderArgs'. Property 'showLoader' does not exist on type 'false'. (tsserver 2339)`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You would have to first check if it's an object. Then you can use `loader.showLoader`: `"showLoader" in loader && loader.showLoader && <Loader />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `loader` is an object, which can be done as follows:

```
typeof loaderArgs === 'object' && loaderArgs.showLoader
```